# Finding the Maclaurin series for the given function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series, euler-maclaurin

I am dealing with a problem that says:Find the Maclaurin series for the function $f(x)=\ln(1+x+x^2)$.

I have tried to write the expression inside the brackets exactly, $1+x+x^2$ as a product of two other expressions and then by means of the properties of the function $\ln$.

I will divide it into two functions corresponding to $\ln$ whose sums then return to an elementary problem, but $1+x+x^2$ has no real roots, I'm open to other ideas and suggestions on how to find the Maclaurin series for the given function above.

Comment: Have you tried expressing 1+x+x^2 as the *ratio* of two other expressions instead?

Comment: Jim's hint is actually really, really clever.

Comment: No,I have not.If you could provide further instructions that would be really helpful.Thank you in advance

Comment: The expression x^2 + x + 1  equals  (x - ω) * (x - ω*) where  ω = exp(2πi/3) and ω* = exp(-2πi/3). So if f(x) = ln(x^2 + x + 1), then f'(x) = 1/(x - ω) + 1/(x - ω*). From here it should be easy to take arbitrary derivatives of f and evaluate them at x = 0 to obtain the Maclaurin series. (All the derivatives are guaranteed to be real numbers, even though complex numbers are used in the calculation, using the fact that ω and ω* are cube roots of unity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1+x+x^2=\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}$$

$$\ln(1+x+x^2)=\ln(1-x^3)-\ln({1-x})$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes.Thank you a lot!